# Queryset is coming null to the django filterset function

Tags: python, django-filter, graphene-python, graphene-django, django-filters

I have a `FilterSet` class for my `graphene graphql` query's nested field. Here are my filter, object, and query classes;

```
class MyModelFilter(FilterSet):
    quantity = NumberFilter(method='filter_quantity')
    
    def filter_quantity(self, queryset, name, value):
        return queryset.filter(quantity__gte=value)
    
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = {
            'quantity': ['gte']
        }
```

```
class MySecondModelType(DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = MySecondModel
        interfaces = (relay.Node,)

    data = DjangoFilterConnectionField(
        MyModelType,
        filterset_class=MyModelFilter
    )

    def resolve_data(self, info, **kwargs):
        data = data_loader.load('my_model_data')
        return data
```

```
class Query(ObjectType):
    all_data = DjangoFilterConnectionField(
        MySecondModelType,
        filterset_class=MySecondModelFilter,
    )

    def resolve_all_data(self, info, **kwargs):
        data = MySecondModel.objects.with_annotations()
        return data
```

This structure doesn't give any error. However, the queryset comes **null** to the `filter_quantity` function. How can I fix this issue?